# How to send a file from PHP to Java via Hessian?

Tags: java, php, spring, hessian

I am evaluating Hessian to do RPC from PHP to Java.

Java is the backend server , which exposes hessian service (via Spring) for PHP .

(Yes , I know there are modern/standard REST-style to transfer(POST) file , but Hessian is more efficient , doesn't need to parse , and can be easily exposed by Spring )

Simple message passings are OK.
One problem is I don't know the correct way to upload a file from PHP to Java.

The java side is simple :

```
public String uploadIs(InputStream is) {
  // do something and return a String
}
```

in PHP side (1st try) :

```
$testUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/hessian/TestService';
$testService = &new HessianClient($testUrl);

$file_stream = file_get_contents($filepath);
$h_stream = &new HessianStream($file_stream);
$h_stream->read();
print_r($testService->uploadIs($h_stream));
```

And the java server reports :

```
WARN  c.c.h.i.SerializerFactory - Hessian/Burlap: 'HessianStream' is an unknown class in java.net.URLClassLoader@1d798282:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HessianStream

WARN  c.c.h.i.SerializerFactory - Hessian/Burlap: 'HessianStream' is an unknown class in java.net.URLClassLoader@1d798282:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HessianStream

ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Hessian skeleton invocation failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: com.caucho.hessian.io.InputStreamDeserializer@647a7c13] with root cause
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: com.caucho.hessian.io.InputStreamDeserializer@647a7c13 
at com.caucho.hessian.io.AbstractDeserializer.readObject(AbstractDeserializer.java:146) ~[hessian-4.0.38.jar:na]
```

If I change my PHP to (2nd try) :

```
$file = fopen($filepath, 'r');
$contents = fread($file, filesize($filepath));
print_r($testService->uploadIs($contents));
```

The java side reports :

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Hessian skeleton invocation failed; nested exception is 

com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianProtocolException: uploadIs: expected binary at 0x53 java.lang.String (... [a lot of binary file content] )
```

How to solve it ? Thanks !

environments :

```
<springboot.version>1.3.0.M2</springboot.version>    
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
  <artifactId>hessian</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.38</version>
</dependency>
```

- PHP's Hessian : 2.0.3

Comment: I don't know why you put a `&` before the `new` ...

Comment: I tried to remove `&` , the result is the same.

Comment: Well, have you actually read the java servers errors? Because it reports the `HessianStream` is an unknown class in java, you should investigate that.

Comment: HessianStream is a PHP class , located in the Hessian's library (java's hessian doesn't contain that class) . I think that was not the correct solution , because it treats HessianStream as a `transferred` object , not the stream itself.

Comment: Well, there does seem to be a problem, since java actually thinks he needs to use or get such a class.

Comment: In this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575872/image-ransfer-using-hessian-protocol-from-clients-folder-to-tomcat-server , the java server is also accepting `InputStream`. I just want to figure out , how to do it correctly in  PHP ?

Comment: What about reading the file as binary in your second try like `$file = fopen($filepath, 'rb');` ?

Comment: Thanks @Master_ex : it works !

Comment: @smallufo: Great! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , Thanks @Master_ex , he points out the correct solution :

```
$file = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
print_r($testService->uploadIs($file));
fclose($file);
```

For anyone who is interested in this topic.